# How add callback (new Ack()) in socket.emit from angular

Tags: node.js, angular, socket.io

I have this in my angular file

```
this.socket.emit('message',this.data);
```

And this code in my backend nodejs file

```
socket.on('message', function(data, callback){
    console.log("****** OnMessage LOGS ******");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    if(JSON.stringify(data) == null){
        callback(false);
    }else
    { callback(true)}
```

My emit is false she need something similar to function new Ack() in Android.

What is this function?

Comment: Could you share the error being thrown?

Comment: TypeError: callback is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the callback as a third argument in your socket.emit method call.

```
socket.emit('message', this.data, function (booleanArg) {
    // Do something with the boolean argument
    // Do something with Ack
});
```